# Are there typographical drawbacks to using .otf font files?

Tags: fontspec, typography, opentype, truetype

Recently I've been messing around with different fonts in LaTeX and tonight got set up with the [`fontspec` package](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) which allows you to use `.otf` fonts in your LaTeX documents (in my case compiling with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`). Given the presence of [online `.ttf` to `.otf` converters](http://www.font2web.com/), this opens up a world of opportunity in terms of font usage -- particularly with the availabliliy of high-quality free fonts available from sources such as [The League of Movable Type](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/).

My only concern with this is that, well, it sounds a little too good to be true. One of the reasons I use LaTeX is because the basic typesetting is just so good. Sometimes people mention that one of the reasons this works is that LaTeX font files contain more information than basic `.ttf`s which allows LaTeX to fine tune character placement. I'm worried that using `.otf`s through the `fontspec` package might compromise typographical quality.

---

So I have two questions, and my naive answers.

**First question (.otf)**: Will the use of original `.otfs`s through `fontspec` result in lower typographical quality than using, say, the default Computer Modern? By "original" I mean `.otf` files created by the type designers themselves, rather than automated conversion software.

My naive answer is no ... mainly because I want it to be no! But I did install Linux Libertine, and the first thing I noticed was a ligature (Th) I'd never even seen before:

[image]

This gave me hope!

**Second question (.ttf)**: Will the use of `.otfs`s created through automated conversion software from, say, `.ttf` files result in worse typography?

My naive answer to this is yes. This is because of the partial attributions of LaTeX's good typography to the complexity of its font files, implying that default Microsoft Word font files simply didn't contain enough information to place the fonts correctly.

Comment: About your second question: You can use .ttf fonts directly without any conversion with XeTeX and LuaTeX. I think however, that .ttf fonts do usually include less detailed typographic information than .otf fonts.

Comment: No. (I have to write some more characters for this comment to be accepted) No typographic drawbacks. Just many, many, many, many advantages if the font is designed and constructed well enough.

Comment: @doncherry: The file extension does not show, whether a font is an OpenType font or not, cf. the Wikipedia entry: [OpenType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType).

Comment: James, see my comment to doncherry. There’s no need for converting TTF to OTF. It won’t get OpenType functionality either. The linked online converter doesn’t say anything about the scripts in the background. Perhaps they use `ttfautohint`, so you would get better hinted OTF files, but actually this is not related to TTF vs. OTF.

Comment: pdftex can use truetype fonts directly as well.

Comment: @cfr: But it can’t use any features of the font beyond what TFM files can provide, so it is just a big Type1 font in PDFTeX eyes (and it can only see 255 glyphs at once).

Comment: There is no difference between the glyphs in a Type 1 font and the same font converted to OpenType with Type-1 shapes. It is also possible to convert all ligatures, kerning pairs and other features of legacy fonts in an OpenType font.

Answer (score 5):

- Regarding Metafont CM vs. Latin Modern OTF: One can argue that one of
  the main virtue of Metafont is the rasterizer - that is with Metafont
  you can get bitmap fonts targeted for a specific device and a
  specific font size, while the bitmaps from OTF fonts will only
  benefit from hinting. On the other hand LM's glpyhs have been
  improved over CM's.
- Regarding TTF vs. OTF: Technically TTFs *are* OTFs, so there is no
  conversion needed. For PFBs (Type 1) only some encapsulation is *needed*.